# Are transformation matrices representing Euclidean space commutable?

Tags: matrices

I'm working on an independent project where I am attempting to find what rotation will result in transforming from one Euclidean space to another, where they have the same origin.  Assumption is that such a transform exists.  I was having some trouble (haven't used my matrix algebra in a while), and I was assuming:

$$ AB = I $$
$$ A = IB^{-1} $$
$$ A = B^{-1}I $$
$$ BA = I $$
thus:
$$ AB = BA $$
Since I was having trouble, I was relooking at the [matrix operations](http://math.mit.edu/%7Edyatlov/54summer10/matalg.pdf) and saw that this is not true in general.

> In general, $AB \ne BA$, even if $A$ and $B$ are both square. If $AB = BA$, then we say that $A$ and $B$ commute.

Am I correct in my matrix operation assumptions?

## Edit

@Onir brings up an example showing that they are not, however I'm confused as to what operation that I started above is invalid. Can someone explain?

Comment: You proved that a matrix commutes with its inverse (which is true), but not that matrices commute in general (which is false).

Comment: in $\mathbb R^2$ rotating $\theta$ degrees and then reflecting over the $x$ axis is different to reflecting over the $x$ axis and then rotating $\theta$ degrees except when $\theta$ is $0$ or $180$

Comment: @Onir, yeah, actually, your right. That is the same with translations and rotations. Or even two rotations on different rotation axes. But if there is an inverse matrix defined for A and B, then why are my operations above invalid? What rule am I violating? Can you only multiply an inverse on the right?

Comment: I second eyeballfrog's comment

Comment: Oh. I understand now. I've not broken anything and my results are still valid. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

So, according to the comments there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with my operations. All that I did was show the community of two matrices one of which is the inverse of the other. It being inverse is implied. This of course is not a general solution for all matrices. I cannot for instance show that $ABC=CBA$ because either $AB$ or $BC$ must appear in that order in whatever valid symbolic transformation I come up with.